# Display just below the link on mouse over.

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I have some links and a div in my web page.On mouse over the link I need to display the div just bellow the link.How to do it so that on mouse hovering any link the div will display just bellow that link only(I mean like a tooltip)?

Comment: Why not use a jquery tooltip library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to do

1. Add the tooltip div with absolute position and hide it.
2. Bind hover event to andchor tags.
3. Get element position using `.offset()` method
4. Set the top and left position of the tooltip div with the values from `.offset().top` and `.offset().left`